# How to calculate 5 days visa-free stay in Belarus?

Tags: visa-free-entry, belarus

From February 12, citizens from 80 countries can travel to Belarus up to 5 days without applying for a visa unless you enter and/or exit from Russia. I'm from one of the countries but I wonder how they count the 5 days rule.

Some countries add the arrival date to the calculation; other countries don't.

Suppose that I arrive at 2017-09-01 at Minsk; do I have to leave it on 2017-09-05 or 2017-09-06?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it's stated on the [website of Ministry of Foreign Affairs of the Republic of Belarus](http://mfa.gov.by/en/visa/visafreetravel/e0ced19bb1f9bf2c.html):

> According to the Presidential Decree “On establishment of visa-free
>   entry and exit of foreign nationals”, foreign citizens of 80
>   countries* can enter Belarus for up to 5 days** and exit from the
>   territory of Belarus only through the State border checkpoint of the
>   Republic of Belarus “Minsk National Airport”.

At the bottom of the page there's a clarification:

> **including dates of arrival and departure.

There's even a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/KOjGWYAKKA0?t=24s) explaining this. So, if you arrive at 2017-09-01, you can stay till 2017-09-05 included.